# Novel's dialogue with a dash in front of every line but the first

Tags: dialogue

I'd like to have a dialogue environment looking like this:

```
« Oh.
— What do you think ?
— It's not correct English typography style.
— I know, but we speak English only because we're on StackExchange. »
```

But in the source I'd like to have something easy to type and easy to fine-tune later on (italic letters, ?, ...), something like

```
\begin{dialogue}
    Oh.
    \reply What do you think~?
    \reply It's not correct English typography style.
    \reply I know, but we speak English only because we're on StackExchange. 
\end{dialogue}
```

I tried to use itemize, but I fails to discard the item of the first line.  I fail to count the number of items to redefine `\item` with `reply`, and I cannot use text before an `\item`.  Can you help me ?

Thank you for any help !

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202231/insert-a-character-at-beginning-of-each-line-after-the-current-one/202245#202245

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following version the environment `dialogue` is even unneded. As far as I understand, it is a logical line of a dialogue, not a physical line in book.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\def\reply{\par--- }

%\begin{dialogue}
    Oh.
    \reply What do you think~?
    \reply It's not correct English typography style.
    \reply I know, but we speak English only because we're on StackExchange. 
%\end{dialogue}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Except that his dialogue seems to be quoted (in the European fashion).  Perhaps the environment could be used to add the quote marks.

Comment: Thank you both.  Yes that was pretty dumb of myself, I didn't think of using `\par`, so I ended up trying to force new lines using `\itemize`, but setting reply as above and dialogue with `\newenvironment{dialogue}{«~}{~»}` worked 100% fine.  Thank you !