# How do I add quotation marks at the beginning of every line of a paragraph?

Tags: plain-tex, quotation

I am trying to do the same thing as what was asked in this question: [Quotation mark at the beginning of each line of a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638771/quotation-mark-at-the-beginning-of-each-line-of-a-paragraph), that is:

> Pieri uses an old style of quotation, where if the quote continues onto the next line, the open quotation mark is repeated at the beginning of each line, until the quotation is complete.

but using Plain TeX.

I know there is a \everypar`macro, but I found nothing online for`\everyline`.

Comment: it's easier for all when you post your code with your question ...

Comment: @MS-SPO Well given `\beginquotation Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc.\endquotation\bye`, I am asking how could I define `\beginquotation` and `\endquotation`, I can't do something like `\begingroup\everyline={«~}` since there is no such thing as  `\everyline`

Comment: there is no simple \everyline. If you want that in plain tex you will have to study the lineno code and adapt it. Or with luatex you could use a callback see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452082/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer LuaTeX could work for me but luatexbase doesn't seem to work with Plain

Comment: @MS-SPO, with plain-tex questions, MWE are sometimes unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With LuaTeX:

```
    \bgroup
    \localleftbox{<< }
    \lipsum[1] % or whatever
    \egroup
    
    \bye
```