# How insert a character at the begin of every line from a source code?

Tags: listings, input, minted, strings, xstring

I'm writing a lecture with many source codes for example. The codes are stored in severus different files. I use **listing** and **minted** packages for formatting the sources.

I would like add character at the begin of every line of some codes like:

- Bash shell ($ or #)
- Python shell (>>>)
- Matlab (>>)
- Other shells (>)

I tried some solutions which have given on:

- [Environment prints same character at beginning of each output line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85315/environment-prints-same-character-at-beginning-of-each-output-line)
- [how to put “>” before lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248944/how-to-put-before-lines)

But both solutions have the same problem when I try:

```
\begin{foo_environment} 
    \input{bar.txt} 
\end{foo_environment}
```

*In both solutions the **linebreaking** are ingnored*

I have tried executing a bash command:

```
sed 's/^/$ /' bar.sh > bar.txt
```

This works locally but I can't do the same in [Overleaf](http://www.overleaf.com) and [Sharelatex](http://www.sharelatex.com)

This is a sample code bar.sh:

```
cd ..
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/
cd ~/.ssh/
ll
cd ~
ls -al
```

The result must be:

```
$ cd ..
$ mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/
$ cd ~/.ssh/
$ ll
$ cd ~
$ ls -al
```

Comment: Could you make this a complete example, by adding everything from `\documentclass` through `\end{document}`?  That gives us something to start from.

Comment: Ofcourse. I'll adding in some minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

With listings you can redefine the numberstyle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=tex,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\selectfont,
  keepspaces=true,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  numberstyle=\numberwithprompt,
}

\newcommand{\lstprompt}{>>>}
\newcommand\numberwithprompt[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\selectfont#1 \lstprompt}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
a
b
c
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`minted.sty` uses `fancyvrb.sty` to typeset the `minted` environments.  `fancyvrb.sty` provides a macro named `\FancyVerbFormatLine` to change individual line formatting.  You can define your own macro for your environment and plug it into `minted` with the `formatcom` key.  Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\BashFancyFormatLine}{%
  \def\FancyVerbFormatLine##1{\$\,##1}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some Text
\begin{minted}[formatcom=\BashFancyFormatLine]{bash}
cd ..
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/
cd ~/.ssh/
ll
cd ~
ls -al
\end{minted}
some text

\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

You can apply the same procedure to external files by using `\inputminted`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bash.sh}
cd ..
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/
cd ~/.ssh/
ll
cd ~
ls -al
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\BashFancyFormatLine}{%
  \def\FancyVerbFormatLine##1{\$\,##1}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Now read the same code from a file:
\inputminted[formatcom=\BashFancyFormatLine]{bash}{bash.sh}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a more elegant way to solve. But the problem is when We use \input{bar.txt} for import a text file insted to use a text into the .tex file

Comment: @AdolfoCorrea - See update in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

With `listings` you can hook into the line numbering code.  This approach is fine if you don't put `\label`s in your code -- I never have and didn't even know you could -- but if you do, when you refer to the line numbers they will be followed by whatever prompt text you define.  In that case see Ulrike Fischer's answer.

Here's an example, which defines a "prompt" (`\lstprompt`) as ">>>"  (python style) in line 13 and applies it in line 14.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{ 
  language=tex,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\selectfont,
  keepspaces=true,                 
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\selectfont\,
} 

\newcommand{\lstprompt}{>>>}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{{\the\value{lstnumber}}\lstprompt}
\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting{lst_test.tex}
\end{document}
```

And the output (using the code above as a test case):
[image: output of above code]

Of course you can insert spaces or otherwise tweak at will.  Here's a $ sign with no numbering:

```
\newcommand{\lstprompt}{\$}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\lstprompt}
```

[image: bash style]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to test your solution and next I'm goin to vote.

Comment: I wouldn't redefine \thelstnumber -- it can also be used for references and the additional code would disturb this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer having used listings without referring to line numbers -- in fact only to the (sub)section containing the listing -- it would seem reasonable in *some* cases to do this.  I also considered whether the line number separator might provide a way in (which in many ways I would prefer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer now I know that putting labels inside your listings is even possible, I've added a note to the top of my answer commending yours for those who use such things.